# How to make lists automatically instantiate on use in Python as they do in Perl?

Tags: python, perl

In Perl, I can do this:

```
push(@{$h->[x]}, y);
```

Can I simplify the following python codes according to above Perl example?

```
if x not in h:
  h[x] = []
h[x].append(y)
```

I want to simplify this, because it goes many places in my code, (and I cannot initialize all possible x with []). I do not want to make it a function, because there is no 'inline' keyword.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I do not want to make it a function..." is premature optimization, assuming that the call overhead in your application will be sufficiently high to overcome the cost of duplicate and less obvious code.

Comment: Using python and worried about inline... incongruent.

Comment: You both are right. But it's only part of the story. The main concern is the burden I have to take with the syntax of calling a function. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very elegant way (since Python 2.5) is to use `defaultdict` from the "collections" module:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> h = defaultdict(list)
>>> h['a'].append('b')
>>> h
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['b']})
```

`defaultdict` is like a dict, but provides a default value using whichever constructor you passed to it when you created it (in this example, a list).

I particularly like this over the `setdefault` dict method, because 1) you define the variable as a defaultdict, and generally no other changes are required on the code (except perhaps to remove previous kludges for default values); and 2) setdefault is a terrible name :P

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this with the [dict methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
h.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
```

or

```
h[x] = h.pop(x,[]).append(y)
```

Comment: `pop()` is cute, but is also slower, because the `h.pop` approach modifies `h` twice, whereas the `h.setdefault` approach generally only modifies the list h[x].  In other words, `setdefault` has a good reason to exist. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setdefault`

```
h = {}
h.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
```